# LINQ select to single row

Tags: c#, linq, string-concatenation

what is the LINQ way of doing a pivot such that rows are trasposed to one string?

e.g.

a select producing:

```
a
b
c
```

would appear as:

```
a,b,c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like you just want `string.Join`:

```
var results = string.Join(",", values);
```

No need for LINQ at all. Note that .NET 4 has more overloads for [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx) than earlier versions - so if you're using .NET 3.5 you may need something like:

```
var results = string.Join(",", values.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I guess this would be the best way of ensuring that there's a leading character: value.Count()>0?",":"" + string.Join(",", values.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());

Comment: @sgtz: It's not really clear what you mean. Are you saying you want an empty sequence to map to "," instead of to ""? If so, I can edit - you shouldn't need to use string concatenation at all.

Comment: the list a b c maps to ",a,b,c".  Empty list maps to empty string or null.  Empty string seems more convenient.  It's easy to do this with a ternary... but these days I'm trying to use more LINQ + extension methods more when possible.

Comment: @sgtz: Your question says that {a, b, c} should map to "a,b,c". Why the change?

Comment: I thought people would relate more readily to the "a,b,c" format.  It doesn't seem natural to some at first to see ",a,b,c" or "`a`b`c".  After your elegant solution just, I just thought I'd ask.  +1 & answer awarded.  Probably, Select(x => "," + x.ToString()) isn't a bad way to go.